# Iterate lists elements within two for loops

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list as

> A= ['loans', 'mercedez', 'bugatti', 'a4', 'trump', 'usa', 'election',
>   'president', 'galaxy', '7s', 'canon', 'macbook', 'beiber',
>   'spiderman', 'marvels', 'ironmen']

and

> B=['loans','network','washington','trump','canon','london']

When I did something as in order to get words from `B` which were not present in
list `A` :

```
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        if j not in i:
            print (j)
```

It gives cycle of loops as:-

```
network
washington
trump
canon
london
loans
network
washington
trump
canon
london
loans
network
washington
trump
canon
london
loans
network
washington
trump
canon
london
.......
.......
.......
```

Why So? All I want to return

```
network
washington
london
```

Comment: In your code, you are checking if an element in B is not inside an element in A and not in A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in B:
    if i not in A:
        print (i)
```

Comment: Can you please highlight that what's exactly I did wrong?

Comment: for example loop four, you check if 'trump' is not inside 'loans', which is true. You should check if not inside the list, whether inside the string of one element

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the `not in` method:

```
not_in_list = [b for b in B if b not in A]

for n in not_in_list:
    print(n)
```

For better clarity, your original code would work if it's written as follow:

```
for b in B:
    unique = True
    for a in A:
        if b == a:
            unique = False
            break

    if unique == True:
        print(b)
```

Comment: In response to your question to @Remi's answer: There isn't a need to loop through the 2 lists to find an element that doesn't exist in the other list. You just have to loop through B once and use `b not in A`

Comment: I iterate only on B list, does it change if you iterate building your array with a `for` instead in a `for` loop?

Comment: In addition, I believe the significance of your code is such that for every element in list A, it prints all its complement in list B. Therefore, you would have a x B length in output.

Comment: Not sure if I'm following your question here but my presentation is simply a shorthand for the `for` loop. They both do the same thing. So, basically loop through all elements in B and check if b is in A.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` difference

```
print(set(B) - set(A))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
A = ['loans', 'mercedez', 'bugatti', 'a4', 'trump', 'usa', 'election', 'president', 'galaxy', '7s', 'canon', 'macbook', 'beiber', 'spiderman', 'marvels', 'ironmen']
B = ['loans', 'network', 'washington', 'trump', 'canon', 'london']
print('\n'.join([i for i in B if i not in A]))
```

**output:**

```sh
network
washington
london
```